# How does Arno stop/steal Howard's first bet winning?

Tags: plot-explanation, uncut-gems

In the movie *Uncut Gems*  (2019), Howard pawns Kevin Garnett's NBA championship ring and uses that money to bet on Kevin Garnett upcoming match. Howard ends up winning that bet but when confronted by his debt collectors led by Arno, Howard is furious about Arno cutting him off his winning.

I am a bit confused by this. How does Arno do that? The timeline of those events are roughly:

- Howard sends Arno a picture of bundles of cash via his smart phone.
- Arno's henchmen see Howard walking into a restaurant where Howard places his bet using the money.
- Kevin Garnett performs well and Howard thinks he has won.
- Howard is confronted by Arno and his henchmen in a car, when getting beaten up and stripped of his clothes, Howard is informed that Arno has somehow interrupted Howard's winning bet. But how does Arno do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watched it again.

- What happened is not described in details, but Arno and his henchmen likely go into the restaurant where Howard places his bet, and talk the bookie out of giving the money back, hence interrupting the bet.